# Solving an instance of Poisson's equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

This question is very similar to a previous one I asked, but with a substantial difference.

Let $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $ such that $$f(x,y,z)=\begin{cases}
r  & \text{if $r\leq 1$} \\
0 & \text{if $r>1$}
\end{cases} $$

Is there a function $\phi$ such that $$\Delta\phi=f$$ where $\Delta\phi=\frac{\partial ^2\phi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial ^2\phi}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial ^2\phi}{\partial z^2}$?

If so, is the solution unique (up to a constant)? And how do I find it?

Comment: It might be truly useful to rewrite your equation using spherical coordinates, don’t you think? Then the laplace operator becomes much more easy to deal with

Comment: No solution to Poisson's equation is unique without boundary conditions. Suppose you found a $\phi$ that satisfies your condition, then $\phi+x$ also satisfies the condition because $\nabla^2 x = 0 $$.

Comment: @b00nheT Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately I know almost nothing about PDE's. This is not my homework actually, I'm actually just trying to help out a friend of mine. As such it would be very appreciated if someone could give me a little more input as to how to work out a solution (if that even makes sense).

Comment: @Spencer would it be a suitable boundary condition for $\phi$  to approach $0$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @Nicol, that would be an example of a Dirichlet boundary condition, and yes it would be enough to guarantee a unique solution. As the problem is stated, you just need to answer that the solution is not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are solutions of $\Delta g=0$, and these can be added to any solution $\phi$ of yours to come up with another solution of $\Delta \phi=f$.

You can expect to find a radial solution $F(r)$ because the right side of your equation is radial, and because the Laplacian has a nice form for radial functions. Assuming you're working in $\mathbb{R}^3$,
$$
    \Delta F(r) = F''(r)+\frac{2}{r}F'(r).
$$
You have a function $H(r)$ that is $r$ for $0 \le r \le 1$ and is $0$ otherwise, and you want to solve $\Delta F(r)=H(r)$. Your function $H$ is discontinuous, but that doesn't matter much.
$$
                  r^2F''(r)+2rF'(r) = r^2H(r) \\
                   (r^2F')'=r^2H(r) \\
                  r^2F'(r)= \int_{0}^{r}s^2H(s)ds \\
                    F(r) = \int_{0}^{r}\frac{1}{t^2}\int_{0}^{t}s^2H(s)dsdt.
$$
For $r \le 1$, the solution is
$$
         F(r) = \int_{0}^{r}\frac{1}{t^2}\int_{0}^{t}s^3dsdt= \frac{r^3}{12}
$$
For $r \ge 1$, the solution is
$$
         F(r) = \frac{1}{12}+\int_{1}^{r}\frac{1}{t^2}\frac{1}{4}dt=\frac{1}{12}-\left.\frac{1}{4t}\right|_{t=1}^{r} =
   \frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4r}
$$

Comment: Thanks! Just one question: are there other solution which 1) are *not* spherically symmetrical and 2)  are such that $\phi$ approaches $0$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @Nicol The difference between this solution and the other solution would then be a bounded solution of the Laplace equation that vanishes at $\infty$.

Comment: @Disintegrating By Parts:how can you say that solution only depends on radius?

Comment: @tbs : what do you know about a bounded solution of the Laplace equation on all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that vanish at $\infty$? Hint: think in terms of spherical means.